# Tool to generate web client using JSON Rest Interface

Tags: json, rest, vue.js, prototype

Do any of the front end frameworks (Like Vue.js) have the ability to generate a prototype form/view directly from various an Endpoints?

I am wanting to quickly knock up a few forms to capture and submit data to a set of JSON Rest Post APIs and Display pages to render data retrieved from other JSON Rest Get APIs.

I don't want to have to go through the pain of having to map each and every field out in a set of .js file, it would be great if the boilerplate could just be generated from interface in a similar way to what Apache Isis does from a Domain model.

The above would allow me/clients to generate a UI directly off the interface and interact with it using a web browser in a similar way one would using Postman, without having to install and understand Postman.

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of these:

1. https://vue-crud.github.io/
2. https://github.com/dionmaicon/vue-crudgen
3. https://github.com/ais-one/vue-crud-x - described in https://codeburst.io/vue-crud-x-a-highly-customisable-crud-component-using-vuejs-and-vuetify-2b1539ce2054
4. https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution/